# What is Bytea alternative in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, sqldatatypes, snowflake-schema

I have a column in postgresql whose datatype is bytea.

the value is like : 10 10 20 20 10 10 20 10 10 20 10 10 20

I want to pull the data in snowflake now, but no idea what would be snowflake alternative

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: [BINARY Data](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/binary.html)

Comment: Lukasz is right. For further details. how are you planning to use this data?

Comment: I don't find anything useful, already seen this document. Also, the output I want exactly like that I have mentioned . for use I am not sure, as my job is only ETL for now

Comment: Given you can bound between binary data and Base64 which was going to be my suggestion, and you don't know how it's gonig to be used, I would store it as binary data, and transform it later to an alternative format if that is more performant for the intended use case latter. Without a use, "fastest/best" is undefinable, thus ether find out how it will be used. or just store it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all, I got in touch with analytics team, that bytea data was of no use, so we have to skip those

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't know how this data is going to be used, then the best approach is to store it in a format that is efficient yet easy to transform at a later date. The closest equivalent data type to PostGres' `bytea` datatype is Snowflake's `BINARY` type, which allows for storage in hexadeximal format (`hex`), or as as printable ASCII characters (`base64`) (there is also a UTF-8 option but that probably isn't relevant here.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/binary-input-output.html